Run every other day, regardless of day of week or month
I want to create a cron expression that runs every other day. I don't care if the day of month is odd or even, I don't care what day of the week it is. I want it to run, then wait 2 days and run again.
Is this possible? The closest I've been able to come is either:
0 0 12 ? * */2

Which runs every Sunday, Tuesday, Thursday, and Saturday, i.e. every other day for 1 week, then restarts again on Sunday, resulting in consecutive runs on Saturday and Sunday, or
0 0 12 */2 * ?

Which runs every odd-numbered day of the month, which means on months with 31 days, we would have consecutive runs on the 31st and the 1st of the next month.  A similar issue exists for 0 0 12 2/2 * ?, which runs every even day, meaning on months with 31 days we would get 2 consecutive days without a run.
Is what I want possible?
